# How to remove curly bracket from the output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

I am new to Python I have recently start to learn 1 week ago and I am stuck here... Any help will be appreciate...

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import psycopg2

root = Tk()

def get_info(Employee_Name, Department, Education,Salary):
   con = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'postgres',user = 'postgres',password = 'Gaurav@31',host = 'localhost',port = 5432)
   cur = con.cursor()
   query = ('''INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_name, Department, Education,Salary) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);''' )
   cur.execute(query,(Employee_Name, Department, Education,Salary))
   print('Data inserted Successfully')
   con.commit()
   con.close()
   display_all()

def search(emp_id):
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'postgres',user = 'postgres',password = 'Gaurav@31',host = 'localhost',port = 5432)
    cur = con.cursor()
    query = ('''SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE emp_id = %s;''' )
    cur.execute(query,(emp_id))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    display_search(row)
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def display_search(row):
    listbox = Listbox(frame, width =50 , height=1)
    listbox.grid(row = 9 , column =1)
    listbox.insert(END,row)

def display_all():
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'postgres',user = 'postgres',password = 'Gaurav@31',host = 'localhost',port = 5432)
    cur = con.cursor()
    query = ('''SELECT * FROM Employee;''' )
    cur.execute(query)
    row = cur.fetchall()

    listbox = Listbox(frame, width =50 , height=8)
    listbox.grid(row = 10 , column =1)

    for x in row:
        listbox.insert(END,x)

canvas = Canvas(root, height = 480, width = 900)
canvas.pack()

frame = Frame()
frame.config(background="Black")
frame.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

label = Label(frame,text = " Employee Database")
labelfont = ('times', 24, 'bold')
label.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =labelfont)
label.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky = N)


label = Label(frame, text = 'Employee Name : ')
labelfont1 = ('times', 18, 'bold')
label.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =labelfont1)
label.grid(row =1, column = 0,sticky='w')
entry_name = Entry(frame,width = 30)
entry_name.grid(row = 1, column= 1)

label = Label(frame, text = 'Department : ')
labelfont1 = ('times', 18, 'bold')
label.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =labelfont1)
label.grid(row =2, column = 0, sticky ='w')
dept_name = Entry(frame,width = 30)
dept_name.grid(row = 2, column= 1)

label = Label(frame, text = 'Education : ')
labelfont1 = ('times', 18, 'bold')
label.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =labelfont1)
label.grid(row =3, column = 0,sticky ='w')
education = Entry(frame,width = 30)
education.grid(row = 3, column= 1)

label = Label(frame, text = 'Salary : ')
labelfont1 = ('times', 18, 'bold')
label.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =labelfont1)
label.grid(row =4, column = 0, sticky ='w')
salary = Entry(frame,width = 30)
salary.grid(row = 4, column= 1)

button = Button(frame, text = 'Add Information', command=lambda:         get_info(entry_name.get(),dept_name.get(),education.get(),salary.get()))
buttonfont1 = ('times', 13, 'bold')
button.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =buttonfont1)
button.grid(row = 5 , column= 1)

label = Label(frame, text = 'Search by Emp_id : ')
labelfont1 = ('times', 14, 'bold')
label.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow', font =labelfont1)
label.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky ='w')
id_search = Entry(frame,width = 30)
id_search.grid(row = 6, column= 1)

button = Button(frame, text = 'Search',command = lambda:     search(id_search.get()))
buttonfont1 = ('times', 13, 'bold')
button.config(bg = 'Black',fg ='Yellow',font =buttonfont1)
button.grid(row = 7 , column= 1)

display_all()

root.mainloop()
```

Please find the attached code as well as Screenshot :

I will to remove the curly bracket which is visible on in the listbox, As well as I wish to print this in a tabular form

[image]

Comment: Please provide your post as code, not screenshots, as a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It would help if you could remove all of the sql code from this example and replace it with some hard-coded data that is exactly the same that the query produces.

Answer (score 5):

You are inserting a list or tuple into the listbox instead of a string. You need to explicitly convert each row to a string before passing to the insert method. Otherwise, the underlying tcl interpreter will try to preserve the list-like structure of the data by adding curly braces or backslashes when converting the value to a string.

Consider this code:

```
query = ('''SELECT * FROM Employee;''' )
cur.execute(query)
row = cur.fetchall()
```

`row` a list of lists. For each item in `row`, you have a list of values for each column in that row.

Later, you add each row to the listbox like this:

```
for x in row:
    listbox.insert(END,x)
```

As stated earlier, `x` is a list of data for each column. However, `listbox.insert` takes a string. Since it is not a string, tkinter will convert it to a string using its own logic which may result in curly braces being added.

To avoid this, you should explicitly convert the list to a string before calling `insert`. The simplest way to do that is to add a space between each element:

```
listbox.insert(END, " ".join(x))
```

If "x" contains something other than strings, you'll need to convert them to strings first. The final version might look something like this:

```
string_data = [str(data) for data in x]
listbox.insert(END, " ".join(string_data))
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, I am retrieving the data from the database but text is coming with curly bracket. I dont want the curly bracket, can you help me where do I need to make changes in the code?

Comment: @gauravnimje: I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thank you for your help. but I am still having an error as 'expected str instance, int found' Can you please help me where I do need to make changes in the code?

Comment: Thank you so much  @Bryan Oakley for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Bryan's explanation was incredibly helpful!!! However, when I used the code suggested,

```
string_data = [str(data) for data in x]
listbox.insert(END, " ".join(string_data))
```

my output was one long line. So I added a for loop,

```
item = [str(data) for data in backend.view()]
for x in item:
    lb.insert(END, "".join(x)) # don't include space between quotes
```

and it looks a little better. I also tried playing around with the code some more and this works well too,

```
for item in backend.view():
    lb.insert(END, "{}".format(item))
```

It's identical to the code Bryan suggested, except instead of join, I used format.

Anyways, thank you so much! This was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Got mine working thanks to this question and Bryan's example that way:

[image: Curly Braces tkinter textbox remove]

[HD mp4 Version](https://i.imgur.com/8fU16xh.mp4)

With Bryan's solution Script:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import sample

root = Tk()
root.title('Name Picker')
root.iconbitmap('c:/myguipython/table.ico')
root.geometry("400x400")

def pick():
    entries = ["1st name","2nd name","3rd name","4th name","5th name"]
    number_of_items = 2

    string_data = [str(data) for data in entries]


    rando = sample(string_data, number_of_items)
    rando1 = sample(string_data, number_of_items)

    my_text.delete(1.0, END)
    my_text.insert(INSERT, " ".join(rando + rando1))

topLabel = Label(root, text="Picked Names", font=("Helvetica", 24))
topLabel.pack(pady=20)
winButton = Button(root, text="pick names", font=("Helvetica", 24), command=pick)
winButton.pack(pady=20)
my_text = Text(root, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 18))
my_text.pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Solution Snippet:

```
string_data = [str(data) for data in entries]


rando = sample(string_data, number_of_items)
rando1 = sample(string_data, number_of_items)

my_text.delete(1.0, END)
my_text.insert(INSERT, " ".join(rando + rando1))
```

Original script:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import sample

root = Tk()
root.title('Name Picker')
root.iconbitmap('c:/myguipython/table.ico')
root.geometry("400x400")

def pick():
    entries = ["1st name","2nd name","3rd name","4th name","5th name"]
    number_of_items = 2
    rando = sample(entries, number_of_items)
    rando1 = sample(entries, number_of_items)
    my_text.delete(1.0, END)
    my_text.insert(INSERT, rando + rando1)

topLabel = Label(root, text="Picked Names", font=("Helvetica", 24))
topLabel.pack(pady=20)
winButton = Button(root, text="pick names", font=("Helvetica", 24), command=pick)
winButton.pack(pady=20)
my_text = Text(root, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 18))
my_text.pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```