# Tkinter listbox has a large white space that shifts with data input

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I need help: I have a Tkinter listbox that displays data from a SQLite.db. When I print the data to the console, there is no white space. However, when I populate the data,

```
for item in backend.view():
        lb.insert(END, item)
```

I get the white space you see in the attached picture. The white space will increase in size and shift depending on the data from other Entry boxes. I can't figure this out and can't seem to find a solution.  My code is here, https://github.com/ChefGravy/PythonProj/blob/master/finance_repo/frontend.py

[white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPyrN.png)

Comment: It may be because `item` is a `tuple` or `list`.

Comment: better show what you have in `item` because all depends on its content.

Comment: you could keep objects on list - ie. `year[1]` `year[2]` instead of `year_1`, `year_2` because then you could use `for`-loop to repeate the same code for all elements in list `year` and this way code would be much shorter.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/63613914/7432